# Set up UISearchBar for a single UITableView page

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a single-paged Table View app using Swift 2.

I've been trying to implement a search functionality via UISearchBar, however, every tutorial I find either uses a Master-Detail application or Objective-C.

First, here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String!]
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "test", sectionObjects: ["1", "2", "3"])]   
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionName

    }
}
```

I don't need filtering, either. I just want to be able to type into the search bar and see the corresponding results (ex. Search "1", the "1" result comes up).

I only have the one ViewController Swift file, and no MasterView Swift file, hence why the tutorials may not've been working.